# Beautiful Soup - Get arguments attributes which contains strings

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Suppose we have a `html` like below:

```
<span title="Sports Football">Football</span>
<span title="Sports Badminton">Tennis</span>
<span title="Sports Ski Jump">Ski Jump</span>
```

I want to extract the arguments on `title` attribute if it contains `Sports`:

So in the end we have a variable `sports`:

```
sports = ['Football', 'Badminton', 'Ski Jump']
```

This is what i use:

```
sports = soup.find_all('span', {'title': 'Sports'})
```

I've got nothing

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.compile` with `BeautifulSoup` to find all `span` tags if the first part of the `title` attribute is `"Sports"`:

```
content = """
 <span title="Sports Football">Football</span>
 <span title="Sports Badminton">Tennis</span>
 <span title="Sports Ski Jump">Ski Jump</span>
"""

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(content, 'html.parser')
results = [i.text for i in d.find_all('span', {'title':re.compile('^Sports\s')})]
```

Output:

```
['Football', 'Tennis', 'Ski Jump']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting nothing because there is no fixed title just named `Sports` and it does not work like a wildcard. If you want to get the attribute value of `title`, you can use `get(attr_name)` on your tag object that you get using `find_all`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<span title="Sports Football">Football</span>
<span title="Sports Badminton">Tennis</span>
<span title="Sports Ski Jump">Ski Jump</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

title = [s.get('title') for s in soup.find_all('span')]
title
>> ['Sports Football', 'Sports Badminton', 'Sports Ski Jump']
```

In addition to that, if you would only require the text for that element, just use the `.text` method on the tag object from `find_all`.

```
sports = [s.text for s in soup.find_all('span')]
sports
>>['Football', 'Tennis', 'Ski Jump']
```

Comment: `title = [s.get('title') for s in soup.find_all('span') if re.findall('(?<![a-zA-Z])Sports(?![a-zA-Z])',s.get('title'))]` what about adding regular expressions ? i think it should be able to extract those containing `Sports`

Comment: I think regex is overkill just to check if the word `Sports` exists, by the way at that point is up to OP's intention on which elements he wants to extract.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the example you gave was just made up off the top of your head but the contents of your spans match what you are looking for exactly - so in that example you could work around by going: 
`sports = soup.find_all('span', {'title': 'Sports'}).contents`
and that will give you the string versions of what you're looking for.

Comment: That will fail, `soup.find_all` returns a list, not a tag object.

Comment: A list comprehension like `[i.text for i in sports]` might give proper solution if your `find_all` works.

Comment: Yeah sorry i was leaving the reader to turn the list into the list he wants at the top - should've been more clear